# Python Parse Json

Tags: python, json, loops, parsing

I'm trying to parse and save the content of a field in a variable of a json response. However my code is throwing an error (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str). What I'm trying to do is to print only some field like DeviceCount or NumLow.

The error looks like this:

```html
    print(json_res['data']['DeviceCount'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

My code looks like this

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
json_res = response.json()
print(json_res['data']['DeviceCount'])
```

Where `response` has this content

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Tipe": "Test",
            "DeviceCount": 1234,
            "bestDeviceCount": 1234,
            "BadCount": 0,
            "LessCount": 0,
            "NumberBest": 108,
            "NumberWorst": 0,
            "NumLow": 0,
            "datecreation": "2015-06-14T09:59:43.907788Z",
            "author": null,
            "expiration": null,
            "id": "000000",
            "Def": true,
            "name": "ThisisaTest",
            "numberhouses": 108,
            "items": [
                {
                    "deviceku": 0,
                    "licnumber": 0,
                    "type": "Test1",
                    "islimited": false
                },
                {
                    "sutotal": 1233,
                    "lictotal": 0,
                    "type": "test2",
                    "islimited": true
                }
            ],
            "status": "test",
            "updatedate": "2021-05-03T06:03:12.400025Z"
        }
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "nextCursor": null,
        "totalItems": 1
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `json2` is a string. Why don't you just use `json_res`?

Comment: Just use `json_res`. That is the object you are looking for, Converting it to `json2` is completely redundant.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Have just edited again to clarify

Comment: You must make up your mind which is the code you are using. Is it: `json2['data']...` or `json_res['data']...`?

Comment: I'm trying to use json_res.

Comment: In cases like this, it is helpful to break a large expression into smaller pieces. For example if you `print(json_res['data'])`, you will see that it is a list. So `json_res['data']['DeviceCount']` doesn't make any sense since the next index must be an integer, not a string (just like the error says). So you either need to do something like `json_res['data'][0]['DeviceCount']` or you need to iterate over the items in the `json_res['data']` list.